# execute code which does the validation on submit button click - jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a submit buttons which sends the info to MySQL. If the submit button is clicked when the radio button is 'yes' and the drop down value is 'please select' I want the validation error to pop up. Currently it pops up when 'yes' radio button Is selected.

```
$( function(){
    $("input[name='discount']").click(function() {
        var isDisabled = (this.value == 'No');
        $("#colour1, #shade1").prop("disabled", isDisabled);

        if(!isDisabled){
             //Please select option is selected
             if($("#colour1")[0].selectedIndex == 0){
                 alert('Please select color');
             }
             //Please select option is selected
             if($("#shade11")[0].selectedIndex == 0){
                 alert('Please select shade');
             }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: @ShankarSangoli. Please view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165182/prevent-form-from-reloading-when-validation-error-occurs-jquery . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$( function(){
    function validate(){
       var enabled = ($("input[name='discount']:checked").val() == 'Yes'); 
       if(enabled){
             //Please select option is selected
             if($("#colour1")[0].selectedIndex == 0){
                 alert('Please select color');
                 return false;
             }
             //Please select option is selected
             if($("#shade11")[0].selectedIndex == 0){
                 alert('Please select shade');
                 return false;
             }

        }
        return true;
    }

    $("input[name='discount']").click(function() {
        $("#colour1, #shade1").prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');
        validate();
    });

    $("input:submit").click(function(){
         return validate();
    });
});
```

Comment: both dropdowns are greyed out of selected yes or no

Comment: You mean when you click on submit button both the dropdowns are grayed out?

Comment: Are executing the `click` event on radio button on page load?

Comment: I think you have disabled attribute on the select element in your markup, remove it

Comment: you are right :). one final thing. How do I make 'yes' selected instead of 'no' when i login?

Comment: I have checked="checked" beside the 'Yes' radio button but when i login the radio box is yes but dropdown are greyed out. I need to select no then yes to make them NOT greyed out

Comment: Remove disabled attribute from the select elements and add `checked` attribute to Yes radio button.